# want to remove tiki-index.php from URL

Tags: .htaccess, tiki-wiki

I want to remove tiki-index.php from the url. (at present this looks like http://domain.com/mytiki/tiki-index.php)

I added the line **RewriteRule (.*) tiki-index.php** to the .htaccess file. it serves the purpose the problem is if I use this, the list of pages in the admin side do not show up.

Please help.

Thanks.

DB

Answer (score 1):

This was added to Tiki7:  http://doc.tiki.org/Tiki7

But you can use in previous versions by adding the following at the bottom of your .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_dir.c>
DirectoryIndex tiki-index.php
</IfModule>
```

Reference:
http://tikiwiki.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/tikiwiki?view=revision&revision=31203